# XMPP server standalone jar deployment and execution

Tags: deployment, jar, executable-jar

I've got a standalone jar that contains an XMPP server (for connecting to Google Cloud Messaging). I can obviously just run the standalone jar and everything works ok, I am just wondering if there's another way to deploy and run this, (probably deploy it to an application server or something?) that would provide me with additional benefits.

Answer (score 0):

You could package your application as a [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) container. Useful way to package your jar with it's java runtime.

## Example

This example assumes you've installed docker locally.

### Create Docker file

Used to build docker image, the official [java base](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/java/) image contains various java runtimes.

```
FROM java:7
COPY xmpp.jar /opt/xmpp/xmpp.jar
WORKDIR /opt/xmpp
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/opt/xmpp/xmpp.jar"]
```

### Build the image

```
docker build -t xmpp .
```

### Run the image

```
docker run --rm -it xmpp
```

### Publish the image

Read the docs on how you can configure a repository to share the image you've built

```
docker push
```